# window.confirm com botões personalizados

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Como faço para que no `onclick` retorne uma janela com as 3 opções:

- Sim
- Não
- Cancelar

Preciso saber como tratar a opção selecionada também.

O `link` vai direcionar para um codigo *PHP* que vai tratar o `ID` passado, se o usuário escolher sim o *PHP* após rodar vai direcionar para uma página, se o usuário disser não, ele vai rodar o *PHP* e passar para outra página. 
Se ele cancelar, então apenas aborto a operação.

```
<a onclick="return confirm('exemplo de texto exibido')" href="pagina.php?id="1"></a>
```

Comment: O ```confirm``` do JavaScript retorna apenas ```true``` ou ```false```, creio que você vai ter de fazer outra maneira

Comment: Faz um script para abrir um modal do bootstrap e também coloque um script para caso se você clique em uma dessas opções dentro do modal. Porem não sei a situação inteira, mas pode ser feito desse jeito.

Comment: Com javascript você não consegue. Use um framework/biblioteca exemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it

Comment: então. Existe algum outro onclick que me de essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um método nativo pronto para isso, você pode fazer o seu próprio ou utilizar algum framework, mostrei abaixo dois exemplos utilizando framework.

Exemplo com [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#teste").on("click", function(e) {
    var buttons = $('<div>')
    .append(createButton('Sim', function() {
       swal.close();
       console.log('Clicou no sim'); 
    })).append(createButton('Não', function() {
       swal.close();
       console.log('Clicou no não'); 
    })).append(createButton('Cancelar', function() {
       swal.close();
    }));
    
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
      title: "Título",
      html: buttons,
      type: "warning",
      showConfirmButton: false,
      showCancelButton: false
    });
  });
});

function createButton(text, cb) {
  return $('<button>' + text + '</button>').on('click', cb);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/4.2.4/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/4.2.4/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


<button id="teste">
  Clique
</button>
```

Exemplo com  [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#teste').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var janela = $('<p>Corpo da mensagem</p>').dialog({
         buttons: {
          "Sim": function() {
            console.log("Opção sim");
           },
           "Não":  function() {
            console.log("Opção não");
           },
           "Cancelar":  function() {
             janela.dialog('close');
           }
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<button id="teste">
Clique
</button>
```